# Dependece in the tensor product of two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, bilinear-operator

Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space, and let $a, b, c, d, e, f \in V$. Suppose that $a \otimes b + c \otimes d = e \otimes f$. How do I show that either $a$ and $c$ are dependent or $b$ and $d$ are dependent? I know how to operate between tensor but so far I don't understant why it should be true as it is not specified anything about $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, or $f$. I would appreciate any intuitive way of analyze this kind of problem.

Comment: This looks like you copied a homework problem, but it comes across as a command to us: "Show that...".  Surely if you were asking someone this question in person you would not say to them "Show that...", right?

Comment: In fact, it is an homework question. I am not asking to solve the problem.

Comment: Your rewriting is a much better way to ask the question!  Anyway, you say "it is not specified anything about...", but that would not be the case when you try to approach this problem by thinking about the contrapositive: if $\{a,c\}$ is linearly independent and $\{b,d\}$ is linearly independent, show $a \otimes b + c \otimes d$ can't ever be some $e \otimes f$.  Build up $\{a,c\}$ to a basis and $\{b,d\}$ to a basis (I mean a basis in $V$). Then see what all $e \otimes f$ look like using a suitable basis in $V \otimes V$.

Comment: I understan, thank you.

Comment: A useful fact about the tensor product is that if $\sum_i x_i\otimes y_i=0$ and the $x_i$ are linearly independent, then the $y_i$ are all zero. Now consider $a\otimes b+c\otimes d-e\otimes f=0$ if $a,c$ are linearly independent, say. What happens if $a,c,e$ are independent? What happens if not?

Comment: If you write the expansion of $a \otimes b + c \otimes d - e \otimes f$ in terms of $e_i \otimes e_j$ then, since these form a basis, their coefficients $a^i b^j + c^i d^j - e^i f^j$ must be equal to zero for all combinations of $i,j$. Another way to look at this last condition is that the sum of two rank one matrices ($[a^ib^j],[c^id^j]$) must equal a rank one matrix ($[e^if^j]$). Lets say that vectors $a,c$ are independent. Is this possible?